# Rounding and truncation in IntRange.contains(Object o)

Tags: java, interval

I made a [`Range` class](https://github.com/GlenKPeterson/UncleJim/blob/master/src/main/java/org/organicdesign/fp/collections/RangeOfInt.java) (like an Interval) that takes `Integers` and  implements `List<Integer>` (actually it implements [UnmodList](https://github.com/GlenKPeterson/UncleJim/blob/master/src/main/java/org/organicdesign/fp/collections/UnmodList.java), but whatever).  The `contains()`, `indexOf()`, and `lastIndexOf()` methods of `java.util.List` can be implemented efficiently (using math instead of iteration) in a Range, making the List interface fit Ranges better than it does `List`s!

Well, except for `contains(Object o)`.  I think there is consensus today that this method signature should be `contains(T t)` for a `List<T>`, but they didn't know that when they added Generics in Java 1.5.  Which means you can pass all kinds of ridiculous things to this method.  Since the underlying range is being stored as primitive `int` values, it's limited to `Integer.MIN_VALUE` and `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.  Which is fine everywhere except the `contains()` method.

Specifically, how do I account for (should I account for) wacky implementations of `Number` or other classes that might have an `intValue()` or `intValueExact()` method?  Also, I really want to warn/prevent accidental truncation, so that `RangeOfInt.of(-1, 2).contains(Long.valueOf(Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1L))` does not return true.

```
// An efficient method for when the compiler can see that
// it's being passed a primitive int.
public boolean contains(int i) {
    return (i >= start) && (i < end);
}

@Override public boolean contains(Object o) {
    // Yuck.  Why couldn't we just have to deal with an Integer here?
    // As it stands, we attempt to prevent overflow/underflow.
    if (o instanceof Integer) {
        return contains(((Integer) o).intValue());
    } else if (o instanceof Long) {
        long l = (Long) o;
        return (l <= ((long) Integer.MAX_VALUE)) &&
               (l >= ((long) Integer.MIN_VALUE)) &&
               contains((int) l);
    } else if (o instanceof BigInteger) {
        try {
            // Throws an exception if it's more than 32 bits.
            return contains(((BigInteger) o).intValueExact());
        } catch (ArithmeticException ignore) {
            return false;
        }
    } else if (o instanceof Number) {
        // No way to check this one.  Does that mean the above are misleading?
        return contains(((Number) o).intValue());
    }
    return false;
}
```

My primary question is whether or not detecting `Number`s is a good thing or a bad thing.  The good error handling of `Long`s and `BigInteger`s could make people expect reasonable error checking when sending Numbers too!  `Float` and `Double` are `Number`s, but auto-converting them to an `int` gives rise to wacky stuff like:

```
RangeOfInt.of(0, 9).contains(2.5); // true.
```

I guess I'm talking myself out of supporting Number - you can call `.contains(myNumber.intValue())` if you need to.

My second-biggest question is that [Josh Bloch's Item 41](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321356683) advises against over*loading* (not over*riding*) methods with the same number of arguments.  Since this one form of the method takes a primitive `int`, the only way it could be confused with an `Object` is through auto-boxing, but if it's boxed to an `Integer` that case will be handled just fine.  Does that make this an OK exception to Bloch's overloading rule?

You may find it helpful to look at the [unit test for this `contains()` method](https://github.com/GlenKPeterson/UncleJim/blob/master/src/test/java/org/organicdesign/fp/collections/RangeOfIntTest.java#L37).

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857420/what-are-the-reasons-why-map-getobject-key-is-not-fully-generic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to [@Smac89](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/100851/27975)'s suggestion, there are two things to consider:

1. Whether you want to be *lenient* in your comparison.
2. Whether you want to silently return `false` for non-integers, or throw an `Exception`.

For the first, you should simply rely on what [`Number.intValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html#intValue--) tells you, regardless of whether "rounding or truncation" (Javadoc) was involved. On a related note, you can refer to what the [Java Language Specifications](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3) say on narrowing primitive conversions. Document this carefully in the method's Javadoc too, something along the lines of:

```
/**
 * Uses {@link Number#intValue()} for the conversion.
 * @param o the Object to compare
 * @return {@code true} if the converted value exists in this range
 */
public boolean contains(Object o) {
    return o instanceof Number && contains(((Number) o).intValue());
}
```

For the second, while [`List.contains()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains-java.lang.Object-) says that implementations can throw `ClassCastException` "if the type of the specified element is incompatible", it is marked as an [optional restriction](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#optional-restrictions). If you surmise that getting a value `2.5` for this particular method indicates something is *really wrong at runtime*, you should then throw an `Exception`:

```
/**
 * @param o the Object to compare
 * @return {@code true} if the argument is an {@link Integer} instance 
 *         and its primitive value exists in this range
 * @throws ClassCastException for non-{@link Integer} arguments
 */
public boolean contains(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof Integer) {
        return contains(((Integer) o).intValue());
    }
    throw new ClassCastException("Not an integer");
}
```

Comment: Regardng the first example, most people aren't going to read the JavaDoc until after this issue has bitten them.  I don't want to publish an API that encourages people to write bugs with it.  I like your second example very much since it fails fast and provides feedback as to why.  I'll accept this in a few days if no-one else drops a bigger pearl of wisdom.

Comment: Great link to the Java Language Specification.  I'm taking that as Descriptive rather than Proscriptive.  "This is what we did so watch out!" rather than "Make your boxed code behave this way."  They made the right choice for speed of primitive operations and compatibility with C.  I'm trying to emphasize correctness, so my goals are a little different.

Comment: @GlenPeterson ah in that case then I'll definitely suggest the 'fail-fast' solution too. :)

Answer (score 3):

Let Java help you. Here is how I would rewrite that mess of code for the contains method:

```
@Override
public boolean contains(Object o) {
    try {
        Number number = (Number)o;
        int value = Integer.valueOf(number.toString()).intValue();
        return contains(value);
    } catch(NumberFormatException | ClassCastException e) {}
    return false;
}
```

**Double**

Your question about *supporting doubles* is good because this makes the class robust, however I think you might be deviating from the purpose of this class.

Your class is called `RangeOfInt` so keep it that way. If the user decides to use doubles for your class, then they should be aware that whatever result they get is undefined because the class is built for integers not doubles. Think of your class as the [range method](http://pythoncentral.io/pythons-range-function-explained/) in python. Now if the user types `RangeOfInt.of(0, 9).contains(2.5)`, since this class was to be used for integers, either throw an exception (which is the right thing to do) or simply let your implementation run it's course and return whatever it wants. Simply put, the user does something undefined, something undefined should happen in return.

**Overloading**

The way you have used overload is good because it keeps the purpose of the class evident. By having one "Object" method, that handles everything that is not integer, you make it obvious that the other method with just an integer as a parameter has a special purpose for int only parameters.

Comment: In a high level language, logic errors should be exceptions rather than undefined bahaviour, I like the first option

Comment: Notice how I never actually used Number.intValue()

Comment: @Smac89 whoops!  I opened this first on my phone and was hasty.  Speed is an issue for this class, so converting to a String and back is probably not practical.  Also, I'd probably let the exceptions be thrown to warn the user they had passed something invalid.

Comment: You know, accepting a String is actually a provocative idea.  Integer.valueOf(String s) does just what I want.  Thanks for this.  It's very insightful.

Comment: Converting to a String handles Float/Double negative zero, overflow, underflow, +/-Infinity, and accepting only Integer values coded as floats/doubles in a way that would be extremely difficult to code any other way.  Preventing fractional parts is good if you are thinking of Range as an integer set, but bad if you are thinking of it as integer bounds on a continuous range.  Also (unfortunately), toString() is not part of the Number abstract class which makes me uncomfortable relying on it for custom implementations of Number.  Still great ideas - thanks!